# TFS2015: what rights in a collection does a release approver need?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

TFS2015 u2. I'm editing a release definition, assigning approvers for an environment.

I have several server-level groups. When I start typing group names in the "Specific users" box on the Approvals page of environment properties, **one of them ("Application Hosting Team") comes up, another ("QA Team") doesn't**. The former is a part of collection admins, the latter has no specific rights. If I grant the QA team collection admin, it comes up, too.

Question - which rights do I have to grant (short of admin) so that TFS considers it eligible for approving releases? Preferably on collection level.

EDIT: Adding the server level group to "Project Readers" will do, but I'd hate to go through all the projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two collection level ways:

- Create a collection level group, add server level group to that one, grant Allow for Edit collection level items
- Add the server group to "Release Management Service Accounts"

Either works. The former is slightly more work, the latter might grant more rights than strictly necessary to approve releases.